# Custom resolver in FlowType

Tags: javascript, webpack, flowtype

We're using a custom resolver to figure out where a certain import points to, mostly to support overwriting default behavior throughout instances of a `base` library. The structure of our project is pretty much this:

```
-base/
-instanceA/
-instanceB/
-.flowconfig
```

We support a special alias, let's call it `@app`, that tries to import files from the current instance, but fallbacks to `base` if the file is not found. So, if an import like

```js
import Colors from '@app/theme/colors';
```

is found in a file from `instanceB`, this will be resolved to `instanceB/theme/colors` if such a file exists, or to `base/theme/colors` otherwise.

I am trying to replicate this behavior using `Flow`, but the configuration mechanism doesn't seem powerful enough ([module.name_mapper](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-regex-string) comes close to this, but it's pretty much only a string replacement).

Did anyone experience this before, and maybe found a hack around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was briefly supported by Flow, but it was removed as of 0.110. These are some relevant URLs you can read:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/293

https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/6132

And this is the commit that removes it:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/87820b8e21e626126e2a8ab7e3a70f253a24bafd